# TYPO3 extbase: Get parent object in model object

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I have got two (2) classes:

## Person model class

```
<?php

class Person extends BaseDto
{
    /**
     * @var array|PostalAddress
     */
    protected $postalAddresses = array();

    /**
     * @param array|PostalAddress $postalAddresses
     */
    public function setPostalAddresses($postalAddresses)
    {
        $this->postalAddresses = $postalAddresses;
    }

    /**
     * @return array|PostalAddress[]
     */
    public function getPostalAddresses()
    {
        return $this->postalAddresses;
    }
}
```

## PostalAddress model class

```
<?php

class PostalAddress
{
    /**
     * @var string $privatePersonFirstName
     */
    protected $privatePersonFirstName;

    /**
     * @var string $privatePersonName
     */
    protected $privatePersonName;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrivatePersonFirstName()
    {
        return $this->privatePersonFirstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $privatePersonFirstName
     */
    public function setPrivatePersonFirstName($privatePersonFirstName)
    {
        $this->privatePersonFirstName = $privatePersonFirstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrivatePersonName()
    {
        return $this->privatePersonName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $privatePersonName
     */
    public function setPrivatePersonName($privatePersonName)
    {
        $this->privatePersonName = $privatePersonName;
    }
}
```

In the controller `PostalAddressConroller` I have got an action which creates  the form to edit a single address.

I would like to make some fields editable only if certain conditions are met. Example: The organization fields on the address are only editable in case the person is of type private person and the address is of type employer.

To implement such a condition check, I would like to create a method on the `PostalAddress` model. But for this, It would require to have a reference back to the parent object inside the controller.

I would like to avoid to put all the logic inside the templates to keep the templates clean and easy to understand.

Is there support on extbase level for such back references?

In case I have to implement such a back reference myself: How do I prevent circular references in general (for example on object serialization)?

Comment: I would handle the problem differently. This is no controller job imho. This is definetly a **template** job. I'd use if conditions in the template to show the correct layout (field editable or not). Afterwards you have to make sure that nobody can just make the fields editable via developer tools for example. I.e. `if($model->isAllowedProperty) { AddFieldToResultArrOrSimilar }`

Comment: I agree with Xatenev here. This belongs right where it makes the difference, in the template.

Comment: @Xatenev Could you please create an answer?

Comment: @AdrianDymorz Done that. Thanks for notifying me (pretty old question). In case you still need help with anything, feel free to comment my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle the problem differently. This is **no controller job imho**. This is definetly **a template/view job**. I'd use if conditions in the template to show the correct layout (field editable or not). Afterwards you have to make sure that nobody can just make the fields editable via developer tools for example.

That would be achievable by adding conditions in the backend logic, for example:

```
if($model->isAllowedProperty) { AddFieldToResultArrOrSimilar() }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the MVC pattern, the model should only carry data, no logic and no dependencies of any kind.
So to solve you problem I would use two different model classes, based on the same table, carying only those properites and validation metadata which applies to that particular model.

Imagine those two models below:

```
namespace Acme\MyPlugin\Domain\Model;
class PostalAddressPrivate
{
    /**
     * @var string $privatePersonFirstName
     */
    protected $privatePersonFirstName;

    /**
     * @var string $privatePersonName
     */
    protected $privatePersonName;

    [...]

}

namespace Acme\MyPlugin\Domain\Model;
class PostalAddressCommercial
{
    /**
     * @var string $privatePersonFirstName
     */
    protected $companyName;

    [...]

}
```

Now you must tell the persistence layer, that those models goes to the same table. You do this in typoscript setup for that plugin.

```
plugin.tx_myplugin {
    persistence {
        classes {
            Acme\MyPlugin\Domain\Model\PostalAddressPrivate {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tx_myplugin_domain_model_postal_address
                }
            }
            Acme\MyPlugin\Domain\Model\PostalAddressCommercial {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tx_myplugin_domain_model_postal_address
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Now you can transfer the logic into the controller and decide there which model to use. You can extend this simple case using a common Interface or abstract class, etc.

This "choose the right model" logic in the controller may be a little bit tricky at times. In general you will need to place some code dealing with the extbase "property mapper" inside the appropriate "initializeXxxAction" method.
At the begining I was inspired by this article in german (for an older version extbase!): https://jweiland.net/typo3/codebeispiele/extension-programmierung/extbase-dynamische-validierung.html
Hope google translate will give you some hints to solve upcomming problems.

On top you can assist the server based validation and processing by some frontend work. E.g. JavaScript tricks to enable or disable certain formular fields depending on the private/commercial status chosen.
You can as well tune the fluid templates to render/not render certain parts depending of the model variant used in controller.

Comment: You completly misunderstood the MVC pattern then. Theres nothing wrong with logic nor dependencies in the model. And if the data, as in this case, is bound strictly to an instance of an entity, it is domain logic. The model is exactly and the only place ist belongs to. Bust dont take my word for it: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176639/why-put-the-business-logic-in-the-model-what-happens-when-i-have-multiple-types

Comment: OK j4k3, you are right. Maybe I shouldn't have used the term "model" but "entity" instead because that is what I I actually meant. From my experience it is cleaner and safer to take all application logic out of the entities to e.g. an entity manager class ehich would be also a part of the model layer and this is what you mean probably. In Symfony e.g. each time I tried to trick some external dependencies into the entity class (because it is so convinient sometimes), sooner or later I ran into "circular dependency issues" so I will stick to my habit to keep the entities as value objects only.